# Grabbing git log from other folder

Tags: git

I'm trying to output a git log from another folder on the server without having to cd into it first.

```
git log /path/to/repo
```

returns

```
fatal: Not a git repository
```

For the life of me, I can't find the switch to tell it to operate on/in a different path than .

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git log
```

Comment: And for commands that need to look at the work tree, there's the `--work-tree` option.

Comment: There are also environment variables that do this as well: `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE`. For full details, see the Options section in http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/.